# Lattice wireframe not creating 3d surface plot

Tags: r, 3d, lattice

I am back with another objectively simple question that has still managed to cause me much suffering. My literal only goal here is to use Wireframe to make a 3d surface plot with a polynomial smoother of the following formula: diamonds$price ~ diamonds$depth * diamonds$carat. The dataset being used is the built-in dataset 'diamonds' from ggplot2.
For some reason my plot however looks very odd, as you can see. It looks more like a series of vertical lines than a nice 3d figure.

This is my code.

```
wf <- wireframe(price ~ carat * depth, data = diamonds,
                 shade = TRUE,
                zlab = "Price",
                xlab = "Depth",
                ylab = "Carat")
wf
```

I tried changing the aspect ratio and that only made it worse, and I tried sequestering the variables... it just made my program crash. I know this is probably very simple to the more experienced coders out there, so I am genuinely very grateful to anyone who could offer some guidance.

Here is my unfortunate resulting plot:
[image]

Thank you so much in advance, sincerely.

Comment: Without your data it is impossible to say. Look at the second example on the manual page for `wireframe`. Did you create a grid using `expand.grid()`?

Comment: @dcarlson Sorry for not specifying, the data is just the built-in dataset 'diamonds' from the ggplot2 library. I am unfamiliar with expand.grid() but I will try using that now based on the example in the manual.

Comment: If you smoothed it out with mgcv::gam, you could use the `vis.gam`method to see a smoother surface. I'm pretty sure that `vis.gam` uses `wireframe` under that hood. See p8 of https://www.datavis.ca/courses/RGraphics/R-Graphics3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get the plot. The `diamonds` data in `ggplot2` is very large, 53,940 observations, so it will help to reduce it:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
library(lattice)
range(diamonds$carat)
# [1] 0.20 5.01
range(diamonds$depth)
# [1] 43 79
carat <- seq(.2, 5.01, length.out=100)
depth <- seq(43, 79, length.out=100)
g <- expand.grid(depth=depth, carat=carat)
```

We will create a smooth surface with a grid of 100 x 100 points for `carat` and `depth`. Now we need to estimate the `price` and then plot:

```
reg <- lm(price~depth*carat, diamonds)
g$price <- predict(reg, g)
wf <- wireframe(price~depth*carat, g, shade=TRUE, zlab = "Price",
      xlab = "Depth", ylab = "Carat")
wf
```

There are problems with the fit using `depth` and `carat` to predict price. The range of the predicted values is much greater than the actual range of `diamonds$price` so a better regression model would be preferable, but this illustrates the process for creating the plot.

[image: Wireframe Plot]

Comment: If you saw my last comment, ignore it I was wrong, this works with no errors! Thank you! It's a brilliant solution. I appreciate your help so very much.